# parsing some XML with JS:

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML file that is used by Flash as string resource

I would like my JS to use that XML as well: is there an easy way to read and parse external XML file in JS ?

like **resources.xml** that contains:

```
<resources locale="en">
<sizeUp>Size up</sizeUp>
<sizeDown>Size Down</sizeDown>
<clearSearch>Clear search</clearSearch>
<wouldYouLikeToReport>Would you like to report this user for abuse ?</wouldYouLikeToReport>
<yes>Yes</yes>
```

....

Comment: One of the first things I tried to do when I was learning js was make a jQuery like xml parser... Here's all you have to do to convert a string of xml to a `XMLDocument` https://github.com/megawac/tfstreams/blob/master/js/tf.xmlparser.js#L61

Comment: I'll suggest to parse it in js object using some XML parser, like jquery xml parser, xml2js, [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser) etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get every node and the text it contains, try this:

```
        var xml;
        xml = '<resources locale="en">';
        xml += '<sizeUp>Size up</sizeUp>';
        xml += '<sizeDown>Size Down</sizeDown>';



        $(xml).children().each(function(index, elem) { 
            var $element = $(elem);         
            var text =  $element.text();

            console.log('elem is ');
            console.log(elem);
            console.log('text is ');
            console.log(text);
        });
```

The output will be:

```
elem is
sizeup

text is
Size up

elem is  
sizedown

text is  
Size Down
```

If you are looking for the contents of a specific tag, you could do:

```
console.log('sizeUp is ');
console.log($(xml).find('sizeUp').text());
```